# Process data while in for loop json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, iteration, progress

I'm working on a experimental project for my own purposes and I'm stuck at the part where I'm fetching my data.

I'm looking for some way/function like the flush() function in PHP for javascript, because I'm fetching about 1000 records from a MySQL database and parsing it via JSON. It takes a while without showing some feedback to the user, page keeps loading for a while and then everything pops-up at once and that is alot of images that my browser has to process at once.

I'm looking for something that will dump the already-fetched-data and send it to my function.

I have an iteration that loops over the maxResults by an increment of 100 and makes an ajax call

```
for(var record = 0; record < maxResults; record+=countPage){
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "json_GetImages.php?limit="+countPage+"&rows="+record,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        global: false,
         ....
            for (var i = 1; i < jsonObj.data.length; i++) {
                var box = document.createElement('div'); //Define new box
                var size = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
                 .... 
                functionMakeDiv(jsonObj.data[i].sTitle);
                 ....
```

Is there something like a flush/dump function in javascript/jquery that i can place inside the two iterations? 
OR am I completely inefficient at work here?

i've tried with a for each, but that's giving me the same result.

With php, you just place a flush()/ob_flush() inside the iteration and it returns the current iteration data (dumps the buffer) (what i remember of it?)

Thank you in advance and I hope you guys understand what i'm trying to explain here :)

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is not a way to do what you are thinking, you could offload the work to the server and then pass down the html from the server.  Looking at what you are doing, I would honestly use angularjs so you can stay away from dom manipulation.

Comment: I could 'echo' the divs via PHP, would probably work, but then the plugin i initialize to order and resize those divs, wouldn't function well? But i might try it, let the server process everything

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where are you placing those divs to the actual DOM, but if synchronous loop stops browser from refreshing layout you could try:

```
var i = 0;
function loop() {

  //Do your processing and inserting elements into DOM here...
  //That's like a body of a for loop, but asynchronous

  i++;
  if(i < jsonObj.data.length)
    setTimeout(loop, 0);
}

loop();
```

Some browsers freeze visual updates and flushing DOM when javascript is executing. What that way of looping does is give the browser a chance to refresh page layout in between actual loops, cause `setTimeout` is always asynchronous, even with delay of `0`.

Hope that helps, cheers

Comment: I also found that: http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/03/how-not-to-trigger-layout-in-webkit.html might be helpful

Comment: Getting the same result, but noted that answer for future references! And my function creates a div ( var box = document.createElement('div'); ) and appends it to a container ( $('#container').append(box) )

Comment: Maybe try making the outer loop asynchronous (and inner like you have in your question)? It should be async already, cause of ajax call, but maybe it's not ...